# switch off on 5v, on on 0v

Tags: switches, switch-mode-power-supply

i have a 2.4 tft lcd shield for arduino. I want to turn backlight off and to light it using the reset button from shield. This button outputs 5v when not pressed and 0v when pressed and led backlight needs 5v to be on and 0v to be off. I want that when i press the button to light on the backlight. I need hardware solution for this. I thought putting a transistor but the transistor needs 5v to activate it. I have a 220v relay which works like what i needed but really don't want to put a big relay to control 5v :)

EDIT: Thank you guys for your answers. I made a mistake when posting. I measured the output from switch but it was connected to arduino rst so i measured the output of rst arduino pin.

EDIT: Looked and measured with a voltmeter. If i put the voltmeter between ground and pushbutton pin i have continuity when button pressed, if not i have no continuity but i have 0v also. So i was wrong that outputs 5v when not pressed i was measuring rst arduino pin so my button outputs 0v and links grd when pushed. I will try with a transistor like you guys suggested.

P.s. I made this think for hobby so i don`t have much experience with electronics but this way i can learn also. Thank you !

Comment: I tried googling, but I could not find pictures of a TFT LCD shield with a visible reset button. Could you provide an image?

Comment: https://www.google.fr/?ion=1&espv=2#q=2.4%20tft%20lcd%20shield

Comment: There is no question associated with this post, this is a Q&A style site, it is required that you ask a question. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Made it with a NE555P timer, like this the display will stay on a while and not while pressing the button.
Thank you all !

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, it looks to me like you are looking for a PNP transistor, and you have only happened on NPN in your research. The following might help. R<sub>L</sub> is your load (the backlight). The switch is, well, your pushbutton. When in the bottom position (to ground), current flows through EC (light turns on), whereas when it is released, it is given +Vcc, and the transistor turns off.

[image: PNP transistor turns on when providing ground to gate]

Answer (score 0):

I think the reset button on the shield is normally connected to the reset line on the arduino, so pressing that button will reset the arduino.  But I'm not sure, you might want to check.

Anyway, to answer your question, you want two things:

- Something to turn 0V into 5V and 5V into 0V.  That's called a *not gate*
- A way of turning on and off the backlight using the 5V from the not gate.

You can build a not gate with one transistor and two resistors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkZsm6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Next, you need to know how much current the backlight needs. If it's not much, you might be able to pick the resistor values so that you can run it straight off the not gate. Or maybe you'll need another transistor to switch the backlight.

---

Edited after you posted your answer (which should probably be edited into your question by the way):

If you have disconnected the reset switch on the shield from the arduino, then you can do what you want without any extra components. Just connect the switch between the 5V line and the backlight of the LCD, which would be connected to to 5V if you wanted the light on all the time.  Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyfs5v.png)</sup>

Note that I've drawn the LCD backlight as a bulb... In reality, it's probably an LED and a resistor in series, all wrapped up in the LCD package. But that doesn't make any difference here.

Comment: in fact my circuit is not the way you designed it.
It's like this http://s32.postimg.org/b3zkq0fzp/circuit.png
And can't modify the lcd display pcb to put 5v instead of Ground
For Arduino is working because if you connect rst pin to ground, resets arduino